# How to make navigation bar (ion-nav-bar) in Ionic transparent?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic `sidemenu` template: `ionic start myApp sidemenu`

It generates a sample project with some useful tools and default configuration.

What I'm trying to accomplish it to make header bar (`ion-nav-bar`) transparent.

[image]

### Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qM3YsJ?p=preview

By default it uses (`menu.html`)

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
```

I asked this question a week ago on Ionic forum - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-make-nav-bar-transparent/49250 - I even managed to find a workaround but it would be so much easier if I could just just make the header (navigation) bar transparent.

---

Here is codepen example that works: http://codepen.io/Samurais/pen/dPRMKL

The problem is - the moment I replace with `1.0.0-beta.1` with `1.2.4` it doesn't work anymore.

### EDIT:

Many people are suggesting `background-color: transparent !important` - **OBVIOUSLY** - but it's not that trivial due to many underlying elements, positioning, translate3D, z-index... I mean that if it was that trivial I'd probably figure it out by now.

Many people are suggesting hiding the nav bar, that's exactly what I did:

> I even managed to find a workaround

But it's a workaround as I'm recreating many default, native elements which is not cool.

Finally... It takes 10 seconds to edit the Plunker. It takes 20 seconds to fork it, grab the URL and reply with the actual working URL instead of some untested solution.

Thank you for teaching me how to become better communicator. I thought that statement **"I would like to make nav-bar transparent"** and the context *(links, plunker, alternative solutions, my post on the forum)* are making it clear, apparently I need to enhance my communication skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/qM3YsJ?p=preview

```
ion-content.has-header {
  top: 0;
}

.bar {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.bar-header {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

*(it would be cleaner to support transparent class by default)*

Answer (score 1):

This is within my css file for the navbar for a HTML website I have this code.

```
.navbar-inverse{
    background-color:#202148;
    border-color: #202148;
    }
```

If you want to make the background colour transparent use:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

**Edit**

I found this tutorial that talks about ion-nav-bar.

http://pointdeveloper.com/ionic-change-side-menu-color/

Check it out.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you edit the plunker - http://codepen.io/Samurais/pen/dPRMKL - and demonstrate it in practice?

Comment: @MichalStefanow On your example I presume you would like the colour blue to be made transparent?

Comment: Apologies. Please ignore my previous comment with link to codepen. It should be link to plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/qM3YsJ?p=preview About link to the tutorial - it's much easier to set a color to something - just add color. It is more difficult to **make it transparent** because there are many other layers, divs, elements underneath...